# JS: Getting filename from URL - JS seems to carry on working in the background?

Tags: javascript

I have this image upload form that lets you select a file or paste a URL.
When you've done that it previews the image and shows the filename underneath.
But when you paste a URL and inspect the HTML it shows that the element that contains the filename keeps flashing purple as if JavaScript is still continually updating the filename.
Is that normal? I feel like it shouldn't be doing that. Can anyone tell me if that's normal or am I doing something wrong?
An image URL that can be pasted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3zHj.jpg

Edited: this is what I mean: [image: the span and filename continually flash purple]

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
     error = false;
    
      var filename = $(this).val();
      filename = filename.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, '');

   $(this).closest('.file-upload').find('.file_name').html(filename);

      if (error) {
        parent.addClass('error').prepend.after(
        '<div class="alert alert-error">' + error + '</div>');
  }}});
});
      

var imageLoader = document.getElementById('myfile');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
      $('#cancel').show();
      $('#click_or').hide();
        $('input:file').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#uploader').addClass('disabled_');
        $('#bg_img').addClass('disabled_');
        $('#bg_img').attr('src', event.target.result);
        $('.file_name').show();
        $('#url').hide();
        $('#image_file').show();
        $('#crop_file').show();
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);}
    
    $('#cancel').click(function(e){
        $('#myfile').val("");
        $('#click_or').show();
        $('#cancel').hide();
        $('input:file').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#uploader').removeClass('disabled_');
        $('#bg_img').removeClass('disabled_');
        $('#bg_img').attr('src', "https://i.imgur.com/j0KblIu.png");
        $('.file_name').hide();
        $('#url').show();
        $('#image_file').hide();
        $('#crop_file').hide();
    });
    
    
    var myInput = document.getElementById("url");
    
    setInterval(function(){
    if (myInput && myInput.value){
      $('#cancel_url').show();
        $('#image_url').show();
        $('#crop_url').show();
        $('#bg_img').attr('src', myInput.value);
        $('input:file').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#uploader').addClass('disabled_');
        $('#bg_img').addClass('disabled_');
        $('#url').hide();
        $('#click_or').hide();
        
        var url_filename = myInput.value;
       url_filename = url_filename.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, '');
        
        $('.file_name').html(url_filename);
        $('.file_name').show();
        }
    },0);
    
    $('#cancel_url').click(function(e){
      $('#url').val("");
        $('#bg_img').attr('src', "https://i.imgur.com/j0KblIu.png");
        $('input:file').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#uploader').removeClass('disabled_');
        $('#bg_img').removeClass('disabled_');
        $('#url').show();
        $('#cancel_url').hide();
        $('#image_url').hide();
        $('#crop_url').hide();
        $('.file_name').hide();
        $('#click_or').show();
    });
    

var dropbox;
dropbox = document.getElementById("uploader");
dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

function dragenter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}
function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}
function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  //you can check e's properties
  //console.log(e);
  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;
  
  //this code line fires your 'handleImage' function (imageLoader change event)
  imageLoader.files = files;
}
```

```css
#uploader {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px; 
  height: 250px;
  line-height: 250px;
  background: transparent; 
  border: 2px dashed #e8e8e8;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #777;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
  -webkit-transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear;
    -ms-transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear;
    -o-transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear;
    transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  overflow-y: hidden; 
  opacity: 1;
}
#uploader:hover {
  color: #999;}
#myfile {display: none;}
#click_or {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}
#bg_img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #eee;
}
#uploader.disabled_ {
  cursor: default;
}
img.disabled_ {
  object-fit:contain;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
#cancel, #cancel_url 
  {display: none;}

.file_name {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  color:#555;
}

button[type='submit'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="file-upload">

<div id="uploader" onclick="$('#myfile').click()">
    <span id = 'click_or'>Click or drag and drop<br>to select an image</span>
    <img id="bg_img" src="https://i.imgur.com/j0KblIu.png">
</div>

<input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" accept="image/*">
<span class="file_name"></span>
<button type="button" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" placeholder=" ... or paste URL to image" autocomplete="off" class="clearable">
<button type="button" id="cancel_url">Cancel</button>
<br>

<button type="submit" name='image_file' id="image_file">Upload</button>
<button type="submit" name='crop_file' id="crop_file">Crop</button>

<button type="submit" name='image_url' id="image_url">Upload</button>
<button type="submit" name='crop_url' id="crop_url">Crop</button>

<span class="url_name"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: i didn't see any flashing purple things on chrome version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Are you pasting an image URL and then inspecting the filename that appears next to the cancel button?

Comment: I posted a picture at the top of what I'm getting.

Comment: okay i now got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reason is

```
   setInterval(function(){
    if (myInput && myInput.value){
            $('#cancel_url').show();
        $('#image_url').show();
        $('#crop_url').show();
        $('#bg_img').attr('src', myInput.value);
        $('input:file').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#uploader').addClass('disabled_');
        $('#bg_img').addClass('disabled_');
        $('#url').hide();
        $('#click_or').hide();

        var url_filename = myInput.value;
        url_filename = url_filename.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, '');

        $('.file_name').html(url_filename);
        $('.file_name').show();
        }
    },0);
```

function call which is continuously running.

Comment: How can I replace it?

Comment: I put it in by accident. I thought that function with the zero meant it would do that with zero delay.

Comment: no, it behaves like infinite loop. you can test by putting console.log("aaa"); inside this brackets.

Comment: what was your requirement for this part?